# angular filter exclude element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

I have an array of objects,  and in the object I have an element `{url:"that happens to have the word search in it"}` ,  so when filtering if you type **"arch"**, this link field doesn't allow for filtering as one would expect for the rest of objects.

It's a pretty big object and I would like to search all of it, I just want to exclude the url element. I can't remove it, as it pertains to a link used in the ng-repeat.  I also have a location search that I probably need to reevaluate in order to create a filter function that handles both.

Any help would much appreciated thanks.

[Heres a Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/AcSOS9WICepoGqc5SLrH)

Comment: `$watch` inside an Angular controller is a code smell. Prefer filtering instead - http://plnkr.co/edit/zcGhOzxRfjUADKQGICFH?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

You can create a searchFilter in your controller.
Put this in your html:

```
<input name="searchText" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" ng-model="vm.searchText">
```

Put this in your controller:

```
vm.searchFilter = function (obj) {
    var re = new RegExp(vm.searchText, 'i');
    return !vm.searchText || re.test(obj.title) || re.test(obj.city);
};
```

Then this on your ng-repeat:

```
<tr ng-repeat="items in vm.myitems | filter:vm.searchFilter">
```